# Eclipse Android SDK: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to integrate the Android SDK into my Eclipse Indigo. I installed the ADT plugin Android SDK  r_17 mac OS and when I go to Preferences->Android, the following error shows up:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
Bad version number in .class file

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:608)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1339)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:376)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1230)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:674)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:708)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:704)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1726)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1139)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(PreferenceDialog.java:1054)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:729)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$4.run(PreferenceDialog.java:375)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createContents(PreferenceDialog.java:371)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.createDialogOn(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:102)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:192)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(PreferencesUtil.java:116)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:53)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:178)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cocoa.CocoaUIEnhancer.runCommand(CocoaUIEnhancer.java:393)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cocoa.CocoaUIEnhancer.actionProc(CocoaUIEnhancer.java:535)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.cocoa.CocoaUIEnhancer.actionProc(CocoaUIEnhancer.java:520)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:4879)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5226)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3607)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Eclipse info:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.5.0_30
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/stef/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/stef/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Java version:

```
    java -version
    java version "1.5.0_30"
    Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_30-b03-389-9M3425)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_30-161, mixed mode, sharing)
```

In the Eclipse, it is currently set to Java Compiler 1.5 and JRE J2SE 5.0. I've also tried with Java Compiler to 1.6 and JRE Java SE 6, still same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely related to [ADT 17 requiring Java 1.6](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes) now:

> Java 1.6 or higher is required for ADT 17.0.0.

So you need to update your Java version from 1.5.0_30 to something more recent.

Comment: I cannot install Java 1.6 so I installed the ADT 16.0.1 instead and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the error lies in the .class file, which is not a part of the java but rather (i believe) the apk that the error lies within (like a hidden panther, waiting to strike when you open preferences). Have you tried reinstalling the apk? It could be that your download came out just corrupt enought to cause problems. That happens a lot with .iso files, but even something as small as an apk download can screw up. Try totally purging it from your system and reinstalling it (along with the tools, the error could be there too). If that isn't your problem, you could go as far as tracking down this so called .class file (using explorer search) and finding what the version number says. Any of these is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I just resolved it by downloading the latest version of Eclipse and re-installed the Android tools and SDK from scratch.

Note that I was only successful using 64-bit Eclipse. The 32-bit version did not work for me.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard. I had Java 1.6 running at the time when the issue was occurring, so I did not have to update the JRE or JDK to resolve the issue.

The solution was given by Satyam Kandula at the link below:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376434

Answer (score 0):

Updated my JDK for my Mac (running Leopard), removed Eclipse & SDK. Re-installed Eclipse (64bit version) & SDK and was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Similar, if not same problem as OP. Tried I number of different things(e.g.): Old SDK, Old ADT plugin. I'm using OS X (10.5).

Ultimately, I installed the 64-bit of Eclipse (eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) and it looks ok.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz